# Unable to get the current location on real android device

Tags: android, android-location, android-maps

I need to get the Lat and the Long of the current location to draw a route, my code works on the emulator but when I debug on real device, it does not. This is how I get the current location:

```
private void gotoCurrentLocation(){
     mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
     LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,listener);
     Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

     if(myLocation==null) { MYPLACE = null; return;}
     MYPLACE = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(),myLocation.getLongitude());
     mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ll).title("You're here"));
}

LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        MYPLACE = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
    }
```

This is the map on the GenyMotion virtual device. When I debug on the real device, the map also has the tiny blue point at the current location like on the virtual device but `MYPLACE` is null and it could not place a marker at the current location. Is there something with the code? Could someone help me out please!!

[image: route]

This is on the real device:

[image]

Comment: are you sure your device has gps and its gps is on

Comment: yes, I'm pretty sure, I use google map before using my app

Comment: do you receive the map ? Maybe it is problem with api key ?

Comment: I see the map, it show the current location with a tiny blue circle, but my app could get the lat long of that location, I add the screenshot to the post

Comment: Try to reboot your device after installation of the app.

Comment: try it but it's still the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could happen because on some devices the GPS takes some time to initialize. **If you request for your current location before the GPS gets initialized you'll surely get a null location value**, since the GPS hasn't been initialized yet.

There are several ways of preventing this scenario. I would suggest you to use Play Services for location detection or you can simply use a library called ,

[Android-ReactiveLocation](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation)

You can request the Reactive Location to get the last known location which will prevent from getting a null value,

```
ReactiveLocationProvider locationProvider = new ReactiveLocationProvider(context);
locationProvider.getLastKnownLocation()
    .subscribe(new Action1<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Location location) {
            doSthImportantWithObtainedLocation(location);
        }
    });
```